# Using hashtags with backbone Router

Tags: backbone.js

I started writing an app using backbone.js.

Backbone.js is handling the routing.

When i add any

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

tags in any of the pages on click backbone redirects to the base page ie root url

Like

if root is abc.com

i click on

in page abc.com/b/c then backbone takes me back to abc.com

How to get past this I want the # links to stay in the same url ?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't defined a callback handler for a particular hash fragment or url(when using the History API), the browser's default behavior is to route you to the home url.

The solution is to replace `<a href="#"></a>` with `<a href="#MyFragment"></a>` and register a handler for the fragment/url when [initializing](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-constructor) your router.